# Title: Printing Function Issue - Image Not Visible on final Print dialog preview in Android using Expo

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, printing, expo

I'm encountering an issue with an Expo printing function in my Expo app. The function is designed to print a PDF image from a given URL. The function works perfectly on iOS, displaying a preview and printing the image without any issues. However, on Android, the preview doesn't show the image, and when attempting to print, it produces an "invalid image"

```
const print = async () => {
    const printImageUrl = await fetchPdfForAndroid(pdfAwsUrl);
    console.log("printImageUrl", printImageUrl);
    setDummyImage(printImageUrl);
    await Print.printAsync({
        html: `<img src="${printImageUrl}" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" />`,
        printerUrl: printerConfigurations?.printer?.url,
    });
};
```

the printImageUrl is base64 string looks like this - data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0x...